# Format Data using mkfs.f2fs Android

Tags: android, adb

How to format android data using mkfs.f2fs

I rebooted to twrp and ran the following command in cmd

```
adb shell mkfs.f2fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p87
```

and i got the following output

```
        F2FS-tools: mkfs.f2fs Ver: 1.11.0 (2018-07-10)

Info: Disable heap-based policy
Info: Debug level = 0
Info: Label =
Info: Trim is enabled
        Info: No support kernel version!
Info: Segments per section = 1
Info: Sections per zone = 1
Info: sector size = 512
Info: total sectors = 105889719 (51703 MB)
Info: zone aligned segment0 blkaddr: 512
Info: [/dev/block/mmcblk0p87] Discarding device
Info: Secure Discarded 0 MB
Info: Overprovision ratio = 0.880%
Info: Overprovision segments = 458 (GC reserved = 235)
Info: format successful
```

but when I reboot the device it reboots back to TWRP recovery

In TWRP when I click on Wipe then click on Format Data it says Formatting data using mkfs.f2fs

So I want to do that using a command, but the above command is not working :(

Filesystems (via `adb shell cat /etc/fstab`):

```
/dev/block/mmcblk0p83 /cache ext4 rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p85 /system ext4 rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p86 /vendor ext4 rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p87 /data f2fs rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p82 /firmware vfat rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p84 /cust ext4 rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p74 /persist ext4 rw 0 0
/usb_otg vfat rw 0 0 /external_sd vfat rw 0 0
```

Comment: Can you provide the mount point for that partition? Also, which device is this?

Comment: @LucasRamage i used following command `adb shell cat /etc/fstab` and here is the output `/dev/block/mmcblk0p83 /cache ext4 rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p85 /system ext4 rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p86 /vendor ext4 rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p87 /data f2fs rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p82 /firmware vfat rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p84 /cust ext4 rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p74 /persist ext4 rw 0 0
 /usb_otg vfat rw 0 0
 /external_sd vfat rw 0 0`

Comment: @LucasRamage in general, please [edit] your question to include additional info. As you no doubt noticed, comments do not let you include essential formatting (like line breaks). I've gone ahead and edited in the information from your comment. Also, did `adb shell mkfs.f2fs …` produce any output?

Comment: My device is Redmi Note 7 Pro

Comment: @derobert yes `adb shell mkfs.f2fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p87` produced the output, i edited my question

Comment: @Rangwa that's odd, the output says it worked. A quick check of the TWRP source suggests that some options may be required; https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/blob/58f2132bc3954fc704787d477500a209eedb8e29/roots.cpp#L328 I got that just from a search https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/search?q=mkfs.f2fs&unscoped_q=mkfs.f2fs ...

Comment: @derobert not working, i first rebooted to fastboot and used the command `fastboot erase userdata` then flashed and booted to twrp, then i ran the command `adb shell mkfs.f2fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p87` it says successful but not working, i was wondering when i press Format Data in twrp which command is passed